# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. I got this error when I wanted to list the products by category?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my markup and code:

```
@model ProductDetailModel

<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="~/img/@Model.Product.ImageUrl" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        
        <h1 class="mb-3">@Model.Product.Name</h1><hr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Catgeories)
        {
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-link p-0 mb-3">@item.Name</a>
        }
        
        <div class="mb-3">
            <h4 class="text-primary mb-3">@Model.Product.Price</h4><i class="fas fa-lira-sign"></i>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="p-3">@Model.Product.Description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get this error:

> 'Detail.cshtml'
> 'InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'shopapp.webui.Models.ProductListViewModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'shopapp.webui.Models.ProductDetailModel'.'

Comment: Pls  publish the controller action code that show this view on the screen

Answer (score 0):

> 'InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'shopapp.webui.Models.ProductListViewModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'shopapp.webui.Models.ProductDetailModel'.'

This means your Details.cshtml need a model `ProductDetailModel` but you passed a model `ProductListViewModel`.Be sure your backend code like below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    var model= new ProductDetailModel(){....};
    //...
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I did not encounter any problems when I listed the product. But while creating the detail page, I defined a different model according to the product categories. Because of this I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

'ShopController'
public IActionResult List(string category)
{

```
       var productViewModel=new ProductListViewModel()
        {
            Products=_productService.GetProductsByCategory(category)
        };

        return View(productViewModel);
    }
public IActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if(id==null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        Product product = _productService.GetProductDetails((int)id);

        if(product==null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(new ProductDetailModel{
            Product=product,
            Catgeories=product.ProductCategories.Select(i=>i.Category).ToList()
        });
    }
```

'ProductDetailModel'

```
public class ProductDetailModel
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Catgeories { get; set; }
}
```